Understanding rendering flow in react native
Below is a piece of my code:
const [person, setPerson] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {            
            const people = await getPeople({"_id": personId});      
            setPerson(people[0]);   
        };
        fetchData();
        console.log(person.children);

}, []);

return (
    <View>
            <Text>{person.name} - {person.children.length} )</Text>   
    </View>
)


In return(), displaying {person.name} only works. But if I add {person.children.length}, I have the error saying "children" is undefined whereas it exists (console.log proves it after fetchData).
I guess I don't understand very well how the rendering flow works...

Well for starters you should use typescript to catch these kind of bugs before your code even runs. Initially person state is an empty object and you're trying to access a property which does not exist in the return statement. Since the data fetching is delayed, initially the person.name value is set as an empty object. Ensure that if the person state is null, return something else.
const [person, setPerson] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {            
            const people = await getPeople({"_id": personId});      
            setPerson(people[0]);   
        };
        fetchData();
        console.log(person.children);

}, []);


if (person === null){
return(
 <View>
  <Text>Data does not exist</Text>
 </View>
)} 
else{
 return (
    <View>
            <Text>{person.name} - {person.children.length} )</Text>   
    </View>
 )
  }


I was so sure I was doing something wrong in the way of ordering things that I didn't think of testing the person value before rendering...
And you're right, I'll try to convert everything to Typescript (but it's new to me).
Thank you :)

Also console.log(person.children) in your useEffect suggest that you are thinking of state incorrectly. I think it should actually throw an error; as the state setter doesnt update the state until the next render; so even after the fetchData is complete person will still be null
